# Updating database with array holding form data

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

i have a form that dynamically loads data to be updated from my database. The first form field holds a question from table 1 and the second form field holds optional answers to each question, say option a, b, c, d. The form looks like below:

> **question 1**

- option a
- option b
- option c
- option d

> **question 2**

- option a
- option b
- option c
- option d

and so on (dynamic). On form submit, all changes to questions and answer should be updated. My problem is that i cant correctly save the questions and options in the right format in an array also how can i update my database using thier unique ID's.

This is what i have so far...

my database structure

[image: questions table]

[image: options table]

**myform.php**

```
<?php

$cid = $_GET['course_id'];
$i = 0;
$z= 0;
$host   = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'einstower_elearn';
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=einstower_elearn;host=localhost', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$question[] = 0;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "einstower_elearn");

$getusr = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE eid= '$cid'");


$getusr->execute();

$count_q = $getusr->rowCount();

$getusr->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  while($obj = $getusr->fetch())
        {
         //Create an array for question ID 
$question[] = $obj['qid'];
}


//for each question get its options from another table
foreach ($question as $key => $value) {
  # code...

$getopt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid= '$value' AND eid='$cid'");


$getopt->execute();

$count_questions = $getopt->rowCount();

if ($count_questions>=1){

$getopt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     while($obj = $getopt->fetch())
        {
          $z++;
$qid2 = $obj['qid'];
$questionName = $obj['qns'];
//form starts here
echo '
            <form method="POST" action="edit_exam_course.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="qid" value="'.$qid2.'">
        <div class="row form-group" style="padding-top:40px !important;">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">Question</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
    //Create an array for updated questions in form
                        <input type="text" value="'.$questionName.'" class="form-control" name="l_title[]" required>
                    </div>
                </div>';
$getopt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM options WHERE qid= '$qid2'");


$getopt->execute();

$count_mat = $getopt->rowCount();

$getopt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     while($obj = $getopt->fetch())
        {
          $i++;
$optionTitle = $obj['option'];
$optionID = $obj['optionid'];
               echo '<div class="rwo form-group">
  <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="' . $i . '1"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-12">
//option ids (unique)
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="questid" value="'.$optionID.'">
  <input id="' . $i . '1" name="optTitle" value="'.$optionTitle.'" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>'; 
}}

  }elseif ($count_questions<=0) {

                   unset($question);
                   $question[] = null;
}
}
?>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" name="update_exam_course" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>Update</button>
            </div>

?>
```

**edit_exam_course.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include_once('connection.php');

  if(isset($_POST['update_exam_course'])){
  //for each question i want to update the question and its options
  foreach ($_POST['l_title'] as $p) {
//query would be here
var_dump($_POST);
      }

}
?>
```

At the moment the contents of the array has all questions and the last option of the last question. what i want is to have an array for each question and their options and how to use this array to update the database. your help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please update your question with relevant DB structure, and the missing query: `$getusr`

Comment: @HtmHell i've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You aren't relating the input array to the question ID, and in the options input you aren't using array at all.

I've added some changes in your code, including optimization - you are querying inside the loop every time instead of querying once outside the loop. Look at the comments I've added to understand better.

```
<?php
$cid = $_GET['course_id'];
$i = 0;
$z = 0;
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'einstower_elearn';
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=einstower_elearn;host=localhost', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "einstower_elearn");

$getusr = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE eid= '$cid'");
$getusr->execute();

$count_q = $getusr->rowCount();

// Initialising questions array
$question = [];

while ($obj = $getusr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Adding question to array with 'qid' as a key.
    $question[$obj['qid']] = $obj;
}

// Initializing options array
$options = [];

// Selecting options
$getopt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM options WHERE qid IN ('" . implode("','", array_keys($question)) . "')");

while ($obj = $getopt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Adding option to array with 'qid' as a key.
    $options[$obj['qid']][] = $obj;
}

// Selecting questions
$getopt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid IN ('" . implode("','", array_keys($question)) . "') AND eid='$cid'");

// Looping through questions
while ($obj = $getopt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $z++;
    $qid2 = $obj['qid'];
    $questionName = $obj['qns'];
//form starts here
    echo '
        <form method="POST" action="edit_exam_course.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="qid" value="' . $qid2 . '">
            <div class="row form-group" style="padding-top:40px !important;">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label modal-label">Question</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    //Create an array for updated questions in form
                    <input type="text" value="' . $questionName . '" class="form-control" name="question[' . $qid2 . ']" required>
                </div>
            </div>';

    foreach ($options[$obj['qid']] as $obj) {
        $i++;
        $optionTitle = $obj['option'];
        $optionID = $obj['optionid'];
        echo '
            <div class="rwo form-group">
                <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="' . $i . '1"></label>  
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    //option ids (unique)
                    <input id="' . $i . '1" name="optTitle[' . $qid2 . '][' . $optionID . ']" value="' . $optionTitle . '" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>';
    }
}
?>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        Cancel
    </button>
    <button type="submit" name="update_exam_course" class="btn btn-primary"><span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>Update
    </button>
</div>
```

In the ajax page do:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

To understand the result and make your code accordingly.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, i cant get any output for the form (form doesnt show), i think its becuase of the `$getopt` query, the `AND` operator might be ignored due to `'` and '"' i'm not sure but i'm getting not errors for the SQL and yet no output

Comment: Instead of `$getopt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid ...'");`
do: `die("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid IN ('" . implode("','", array_keys($question)) . "') AND eid='$cid'");` and tell me what's the output

Comment: `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qid IN ('58027e82e62e3','58027e833dd54','58027e8371483','58027e8371494') AND eid='3'` The query appears to be fine, but the form doesnt output anything

Comment: Only the buttons cancel and update show so i wrote a piece of code to print some text if the button is clicked but nothing happens. Any ideas as to why the form isn’t working?

Comment: The problem is with the arrays i cant figure out why but when i output other data before any array declarations i get an output but everything after that just comes up blank

Comment: You should display errors when you are developing, put this at the top of your page: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);` I guess there is a possiblity that you are using a very old PHP version that don't have a short array decleration, in that case replace every `$array = [];` with `$array = array();`

Comment: I dont get any errors still, i’ve also changed the code to $array = array(); what i’ve discovered is when i do var_dump on the question array i get the array result ok. But where you have declared the $options array variable. I did var_dump on it but it was empty. I used die on every query but that was ok.